# At Lake Silencio, why did the Teselecta need to show the Doctor regenerating if he was the last regeneration?

Tags: doctor-who

Since he was the last regeneration, the Teselecta could have just showed him dead.

Comment: Er, because it wasn't common knowledge that the 11th Doctor was in fact that 12th Doctor; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Doctor?

Comment: You mean Because the ass pull retcon wasn't established yet?

Comment: @cde - The retcon that was necessary because Eccleston refused to come back for the 50th Anniversary episode.

Comment: @Richard meh, they could have easily written 8th into the role.

Comment: @cde - That wouldn't have resulted in the same kind of publicity for the series; *“So all of this led me to the idea that if you’re going to sell to the Not-We audience a Doctor who essentially they haven’t seen before, then you have a freer hand than saying it has to be one of the ones you’ve already had. And it was predicated in getting an enormous star to be able to do it. We got John Hurt, so that was cool! Think of the fuss it’s created for us!”*; http://www.themarysue.com/moffat-eccleston-dw-50th/

Answer (score 3):

In reality, it is simply because the War Doctor was not a planned addition by the time of Series 6's writing. That incarnation was made up specifically for the 50th anniversary special when Christopher Eccleston declined to take part in it.

However, story-wise, while it is true that the nominal "eleventh" Doctor was actually the thriteenth incarnation of the Doctor, that knowledge was not widespread *at all*. Consider that the War Doctor incarnation was very firmly established as a secret; something that the Doctor had tried to bury the memory of for centuries. Additionally, the meta-crisis regeneration in "The Stolen Earth" was witnessed by all of three people. In the eyes of various alien societies all across the universe, all of whom the Teselecta gambit were meant to deceive, there was no numerical discrepancy - the Doctor that looked like Matt Smith was the eleventh incarnation. To account for this, and to maintain the illusion that the War incarnation had never existed, the Doctor would have instructed the Teselecta crew to simulate a regeneration upon being shot.

The death had to *look* real and convincing, and since most everybody aside from the Doctor would have expected him to regenerate at that moment (due to the not knowing about the War Doctor or the meta-crisis), the Doctor must have factored that into his planned scenario in order to make it just that.

In short, he lied.

Answer (score 2):

That was to show the finality of the killing.

If they had simply shot the Doctor, the others might have waited for him to regenerate, or tried to heal him considering that they were assuming that he would regenerate..

But River, Silents knows that if a Time Lord is killed *while* he/she is regenerating, they are dead for good... That way, they showed to the Silents that the Doctor was no more...

Comment: Could the descriptions of it occuring have indicated to the Doctor that it wasn't really him dying?

Comment: @kaine - i didn't quite get you??

Comment: The doctor was the only one who knew that he shouldnt regenerate.  If he finds out he started to regenerate, could that tell him something was off?

Comment: @kaine - check out the comments below the question. Back then, it wasn't established that it was his last regeneration. That looks like a minor plot I feel.

Comment: I am aware of that. While the writers didnt know that (before the retcon) the character would have.  Ergo trying to make sense of it in the context we currently understand.

Comment: I still didn't get you. Considering the events of the end of that episode, The Doctor himself scripted the whole scene. He must've instructed the Teselcta to emulate a regeneration so as to make it look real....

Comment: That story spans the whole season. I mean it could act as a message from "currently getting fake shot" doctor to "worrying about how he is going to get out of this one" past doctor.  The message is "this death looks like people think it should but something is off. It is fake and there is a way for you to survive."  I dont know if anyone told him he started to regenerate which is the possible hole in this theory which as stated is obviously not intentional as the john hurt doctor didnt exist yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19840/discussion-between-ash-k29-and-kaine).